# Boot order changes every time I select an entry from boot menu

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi

I have 2 hard disks, each one has a different Windows 10 installation. I want to boot by default with the same hard disk, every time, unless I press F8 (that shows quick boot menu) and choose the other disk occasionally.

Then problem is that after I boot from the other disk by pressing F8, such disk becomes the first option in the boot order. So, I don't know who is changing the boot order: BIOS (motherboard is Asus z170 pro gaming) or Windows.

Please, can you help me to prevent changing default boot disk each time I select it from the boot menu?